# Theme customization in login form in drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I need to have my login title on header,after clicking on login, login form should appear in left sidebar in drupal 7, what all customization i have to do?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps mentioned below to customize login form (like Login title, location and page) in drupal:

```
1. Login to admin panel.
2. Navigate to structure>>block.
3. search user login. Click on edit to add title, region and more.
4. Save the block.
```